# vCenter 7 postgres ERROR: permission denied for view vpxv_hosts

Tags: permissions

We just upgraded this **VCenter** server to this version, actually 2 of them and they are both giving this error. We have tried the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA vc to our_user` command and it did not help.
Everytime we run the "grant select on all tables in schema vc to "our_user" we get below warnings:

```
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_vcdb_ndu_exp"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_vcdb_ndu_exp_app"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_host_service_mode_state"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_vcdb_proc_trk"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_vcdb_ndu_rvt"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_hist_stat1"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_hist_stat2"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_hist_stat3"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpx_hist_stat4"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_entity"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_hist_stat_daily"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_hist_stat_weekly"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_hist_stat_monthly"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_hist_stat_yearly"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_stat_counters"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_stat_historical_intervals"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_host_datastore"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_host_network"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vm_datastore"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vm_network"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_compute_resource_network"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_compute_resource"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_hosts"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vms"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_farmgroups"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vmgroups"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_fields"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_host_fields"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vm_fields"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_alarms"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_templates"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_tasks"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_event_all"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_event_arg"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_events"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_entity_moid"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_ds_lun_info"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_vm_rdm_lun_info"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_sn_rdm_lun_info"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_datastore"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_host_cpu"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_object_type"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_customized_field"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_compute_resource_das_vm"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_compute_resource_drs_vm"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_entity_vmop_count"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "vpxv_snapshot"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to PostgreSQL, and as it turned out I was not in the correct Database path. So the account I was logged in with did not have have the role to grant the privileges I was trying to grant.
Once I got that corrected and logged into the correct Database everything worked fine.